# react native - push notification without Google Play Service

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I researched about the push notification and able to do it using the Firebase.

Is there anyway we can do a push notification without using the Firebase or even the Google Play Service?

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use services like [CleverTap](https://clevertap.com/ppc/push-notifications-live-demo/?utm_campaign=1775127798&utm_source=google&utm_medium=ppc&utm_content=343065009313&utm_term=push%20notifications&adgroupid=67886737086&utm_keyword=1775127798&https://clevertap.com/ppc/push-notifications-live-demo/&_bt=343065009313&_bk=push%20notifications&_bm=p&_bn=g&_bg=67886737086&gclid=Cj0KCQiAqNPyBRCjARIsAKA-WFzZvE9e8AEFY2q3dv6Syfo-qxjdGJ9DVYpdpmQ1cohpWsT8Q5Z-oGoaAqKBEALw_wcB) or [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com) with your app. Both them are available as react-native SDKs.

[clevertap-react-native](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-react-native) SDK

[react-native-onesignal](https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal) SDK

Apart form that few [other services](https://thetool.io/2020/top-push-notifications-tools-services)

But my suggestion is to move with [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). Because it has wide community plus good documentation, And main thing is it IS FREE. most of above are not free services.

If is this regarding Huawei scenario you can use [HMS PushKit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-pushkit), but to use it on react-native you have to create a react-native wrapper for Huawei PushKit

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will try both suggested SDK.

Comment: @LuongTruong Please check I have update the answer again regarding the Huawei.

Comment: I decided to use Firebase. Thank you for your time

Comment: @EL173 if i need to support for Huawei and other Android devices in my react native app, i need to integrate both firebase + hms push kit? is there any single solution sdk?

Comment: Hi @AnnieTan, As of current situation in react-native Yes you have integrate both kits and do the segregation from your app code

Answer (score 1):

for some devices, you can use the room which provides push services to realize it.
for example the MIUI push or Samsung push. but you have to combine them all. so I suggested you use the google push services.

or you can use some third party push services. this [article](https://hackernoon.com/5-best-push-notification-services-to-consider-for-your-next-mobile-app-project-9b4c2e8dd1db) give some about them

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I read the article. AWS is one of my next target to do the push notification, However, it looks like AWS also need Google Play Service to work on all devices. Is that true, bro?

Comment: for some devices, if you want to push notification more efficiently, it has to use google play services. or when the app was killed, the notification can not be received. the reason is a long Http connection for notification

Comment: Thank you for your time. I decided to use Firebase now :)

Comment: @LuongTruong does Firebase notifications work without Google Play Services? I'm also looking for a solution to this

Comment: @RafaelZ.B.Bravo: to be honest, the answer is no :(

Comment: @LuongTruong thank you! I ended up using [Pushy.me](http://pushy.me), it works without Google Services. It's a paid service though.

Comment: @RafaelZ.B.Bravo: Thank you for an option